# Camunda MyBatis and Java 12 Issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis, camunda

I'm trying to configure Camunda with Spring Boot project. I'm using MySQL 8.0.16, Spring Boot 2.1.4.RELEASE and OpenJDK 12.0.

Camunda dependencies:

- Camunda Spring Boot Starter Web App (3.2.1)
- Camunda Spring Boot Starter Rest (3.2.1)
- Camunda Spring Boot Starter (3.2.1)

When I'm trying to run my project I got the error that is connected with MyBatis:

> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred .
>
> WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.ibatis.reflection.Reflector to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
>
> WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.ibatis.reflection.Reflector
> WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
> WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: This issue has been [fixed](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/1156) in MyBatis 3.5.0. But Camunda [specifies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.camunda.bpm.springboot.project/camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-root/3.3.1) an older version as its dependency even in its latest version, it seems. Try adding MyBatis [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mybatis/mybatis/3.5.1) explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and as Camunda comes with the preset MyBatis dependency, I used the following VM flag to suppress the warnings.

```
--illegal-access=deny
```